# How can I use the environment variables inside a regular expression in awk?

Tags: shell-script, awk, regular-expression, environment-variables

```
#!/bin/sh
ALTER="1153"
NAME="aio"

for i in $(ps -eo pid,etime,comm | \
  awk -v alt="$ALTER" -v name="$NAME" '$2~/[^0-alt]-/ && $3~/name/{print$1} ');
do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: Please clarify what you intend this to do. `$2 ~ /[^0-1153]/` would not make sense. That would match if the etime contains a character other than 0,1,5 or 3.

Comment: I tried to print out the PID's of all aio programs older than 1153 days

Comment: 1153 **days**? What is the system uptime?

Comment: 11:36:45 up 1155 days, 18:20 awesome right? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use **awk**:

```
for pr in $(pgrep $NAME); do 
    elapse=$(ps -o etime= -p $pr)
    [ "${elapse%-*}" -gt "$ALTER" ] && echo $pr
done
```

or according  [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas)' comment

```
ps -C $NAME -o pid=,etime= | awk '$2 + 0 > a && /-/ {print $1}' a="$ALTER"
```

Comment: "etimes" does not work for me.

Comment: There is no need to call the `[`, `echo` and `ps` commands several times in sequence where the whole thing can be done with **one** invocation of `ps` and `awk` running concurrently.

Comment: Thank you so much it finally worked!
but I don't get the {elapse%-*} part. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: `{elapse%-*}` removes part of *elapse* variable from `-` upto the end

Comment: oh okay makes sense.
Do you know what I have to change if I want to run it in csh? It says a variable is illegal. And after a few tests I know that it is one after the "for".

Comment: @JuM see updated

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
awk -v alt="$ALTER" -v name="$NAME" '
   $2 ~ /-/ && $2 >= alt && $3 ~ name{print $1}' file
```

- `$2 ~ /-/`: checks that the number of days is included.
- `$2 >= alt`: checks that the number of days in `etime` is greater than `$ALTER`.
- `$3 ~ name`: searches for the value of `name` (`$NAME`) in the 3rd field.

---

Another pure `bash` solution:

```
ps -eo pid,etime,comm | while read p e n; do
  if [[ $n =~ $NAME ]] && [[ $e =~ \- ]] && [ "${e%%-*}" -gt "$ALTER" ]; then 
    echo $p
  fi
done
```

- `while read p e n` stores the pid, the etime and the name of the command in the variables `$p`, `$e` and `$n`.

  - `[[ $n =~ $NAME ]]`: checks if the command has `$NAME` in it
  - `[[ $e =~ \- ]]`: checks if the etime has a dash (-) in it (means the process runs more than a day)
  - `[ "${e%%-*}" -ge "$ALTER" ]`: checks if the day counter of etime is greather or equal than the value in `$ALTER`
- If all of the above is met, print the pid: `echo $p`

Comment: No I want that the age should be more than the value of the variable (that's why I use the negation) the problem is I always get the error report that 1-$alt is an invalid range end. If I add the age myself so 1153 instead of the variable the script works just fine. The Script works if I remove the variables and just add the values myself but I want it to work with the variables

Comment: Then just use `$2>alt`, instead of `$2<alt`. Then the second field should be greater than the value in `$ALTER`

Comment: Now I get following error report:
awk: $2<alt-/ && $3~/aio/{print$1}
awk:            ^ syntax error
awk: $2<alt-/ && $3~/aio/{print$1}
awk:                                 ^ syntax error

(the / after $alt- is marked and the {

Comment: If I add a / before the $2 there is no more error report but the PID's dont  get print out